# I install cocoapods the command " pod setup" gives me this error

Tags: installation, cocoapods

I install cocoapods
the command " pod setup" gives me this error
[error after pod setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZ6B8.png)

Comment: Show us your Podfile

Comment: I have not yet PODFILE since I 'm still in pod setup

Answer (score 0):

Run 'pod init' instead of 'pod setup'

Comment: Unable to add a source with url `https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git` named `master`.
You can try adding it manually in `~/.cocoapods/repos` or via `pod repo add`.